# Custom prompt box using javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a custom prompt box. So far I used a hidden div that is shown on a button click with javascript:

```
function openPromptBox() {
var pos = FindXY(document.promptForm);
var cont = $('promptContainer');
var searchBox = $('promptBox');

searchBox.style.left = (pos.x - 20) + "px";
searchBox.style.top = (document.body.scrollTop + 100) + "px";

cont.style.display = "block";
}
```

here is the div:

```
<div id="promptContainer">
<div id="promptBox">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="result" id="result" size="25"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnOK" value="OK" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</div>          
</div>
```

Now I need to return to the function `openPromptBox` the value of textbox `result` whenever `btnOK` button is clicked. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to use the result value inside openPromptBox() ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are using jquery so here would be a solution:

```
$('#result').val()
```

Would take the current value (the text / number / etc) out of your input

now you can simply pass it to your function like so:

```
$('#btnOK').on('click', function() {

  openPromptBox($('#result').val());

});
```

That's it.

In the definition of your function you should probably add a parameter which is then used in the function:

```
function openPromptBox(textFromInput){

   alert(textFromInput);

}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01bkkgzd/2/

**UPDATE:**

Without JQuery it would be:

```
document.getElementById("result").value
```

which will get the value of the input

Example for the onclick action and the following function call

```
document.getElementById("btnOK").addEventListener('click', function() {

  openPromptBox(document.getElementById("result").value);

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01bkkgzd/5/

Comment: I am not using jquery. `$` is a custom function but it is all plain javascript

Comment: @toerd: don't put `var` in front of the function parameter. It will produce an error. Function arguments behave like local variables anyway. `function openPromptBox(textFromInput){
   alert(textFromInput);
}`

Comment: @ElenaDBA -> Ill try provide a plain javascript solution

Comment: @ElenaDBA hopefully this update will help you completing your task (: have a nice evening!

Answer (score -1):

No, this is impossible.

A `prompt` opens a modal dialog and blocks all further JavaScript (and interaction with the page) until one of the buttons is activated by the user.

When you insert form fields into an HTML document, there is no blocking (nor could there be, since that would prevent the user from filling in the form).

You need to bind an event listener to the form fields you have created and then handle the response going forwards just like any other [asynchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).